# How to copy an external link to local folder in terminal?

Tags: command-line, mac

I would like to know how to copy an external link to the local folder in terminal.

I have searched for this but the results are mostly about symbolic-link using `ln -s`, which is not what I am looking for.

If you have any ideas or suggestions on wordings of my question, please feel free to comment. Thanks!

Comment: What type of external link ?

Comment: Say an image from: https://em-content.zobj.net/thumbs/120/apple/354/grinning-face-with-big-eyes_1f603.png. Or the raw code from github.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the info to the question!

Comment: Just run `wget <some-link>`?